# Azure "~/maintenance" route fails

Tags: asp.net, azure, routes, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-web-app-service

I have an ASP.NET Core (.NET Framework) web app with a handful of controllers, one of which is called 'Maintenance'. I can browse to all controllers successfully when debugging. Once I deploy to my Azure Web App, I can't browse to anything under the /maintenance route - I get the following error:

```
The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.
```

I have tried renaming the controller and views directory to anything other than 'Maintenance' and it works fine. I have tried deleting all files from the web server and republishing but it made no difference.

Is "/maintenance" a reserved route under Azure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is "/maintenance" a reserved route under Azure?

No, I just created a simple ASP.NET Web application and publish it to my Azure Web App. I can view the "/maintenance" path of my web app. Please enable the application log and view the error message or [remote debug your application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio#remotedebug) to find out the root cause.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for checking that. I just found that someone had created a virtual directory called maintenance...